# Не работает @client.event, подсвечивается красным

Tags: python, discord.py, discord

Если пишу @client.event, то она подсвечивается красным

```
@client.event
async def on_message(message):
    print(message.content)
```

В данном случае @client.event подсвечивается красным курсивом, подскажите, пожалуйста, как это исправить.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Было бы не плохо получить весь код. Но есть предположения что переменная `client` не хранит объект класса `discord.Client` или `discord.ext.commands.Bot`
Проверьте код для `client` выше.
Вот пример:

```py
client = discord.Client(intents=discord.Intents.all())
```

или если хотите использовать бот:

```py
from discord.ext import commands

client = commands.Bot("!", intents=discord.Intents.all())
```

Обратите внимание что я использовал все намерения, измените это если используете не все